# Division operator numbers in c#

Tags: c#

I get divide in c#

```
10 / 25 = 0.4
```

in c#

```
double ab =   10 % 25;
label1.Text = ab.ToString();
```

Why the results 10?

Comment: Don't you find any difference between `/` and `%` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`%` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) is remainder operator. It calculates the remainder when you divide first operand to second one.

```
10 = 25 * 0 + 10
```

You need to use [`/` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx) with at least one floating point number to get `0.4` as a result. Otherwise, this operators calculates [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) for two integer operands and it's disregards fractional  part.

```
10.0 / 25 = 0.4
10.0 / 25.0 = 0.4
10 / 25.0 = 0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator. So, 10 is divided by 25 and the rest (which is not fully dividable by 25) is being returned.

See the following examples:

```
25 % 25 = 0
25 % 6  = 1
25 % 10 = 5
```

You see - 10 % 25 = 10 is correct, as 10 is not dividable by 25 and it thus returns 10.

That way it will be working:

```
double ab =   10 / 25;
label1.Text = ab.ToString();
// label1.Text is now "0.4"
```

Comment: That's wrong. `10 / 25` returns `0` no matter which type you wanna assign it.

Answer (score 0):

To do `10 / 25 = 0.4`

you have to do

```
double ab = (double)10 / (double)25;
```

because The % is the modulo operator. `10 % 25 = 10` is correct only.

Comment: That's wrong. `10 / 25` returns `0` no matter which type you wanna assign it.

Comment: if both variables are double it will return 0.4.  check the modified answer.